# Data Binding issue using NotificationBase

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, uwp

```
Custom_View.xaml

    <UserControl>
        <local:Custom_Text_Field
            Custom_Text_Field_Color="{x:Bind ViewModel.Color1 , Mode=TwoWay}">
        </local:Custom_Text_Field>
        <local:Custom_Text_Field
            Custom_Text_Field_Color="{x:Bind ViewModel.Color2 , Mode=TwoWay}">
        </local:Custom_Text_Field>
        <Button Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.ChangeColor"/>
    </UserControl>

Custom_View.cs

    public sealed partial class Custom_View : UserControl
    {
        public Custom_View_VM ViewModel { get; set; }
        public Custom_View()
        {
            ViewModel = new Custom_View_VM();
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

Custom_View_VM.cs

    public class Custom_View_VM : NotificationBase
    {
        public Brush Color1 { get; set; }
        public Brush Color2 { get; set; }
        public void  ChangeColor{//change color1 or color2};
    }
```

I used the NotificationBase class from this example: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnshews_blog/2015/09/09/a-minimal-mvvm-uwp-app/

If I affect values for Color1 or Color2 in the constructeur, it work (change the view), but after a call to ChangeColor, values in the View model are changed but it didn't impact the view.

Comment: Normaly you would create DependencyProperties in code-behind instead of a ViewModel. The a consumer of your control can bind the dependency properties of you control to their ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have created DependencyProperties in the Custom_Text_Field code behind,  i created a ViewModel for my Custom_View,  because the UI is more complexe than my exemple and he is linked whith data from a web service : (

Comment: There are 2 different types of binding here: binding to the code behind (using Dependancy Property) and binding tothe ViewModel (using INotifyPropertyChanged) - it's not clear which one doesn't work: the Border (with the DP) or the Text Fields (binded to the VM)?

Comment: Novitchi S solve my probleme, it was the binding to the VM =)

Comment: I've removed the dependancy proprty section to clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the UI to update it should receive a `PropertyChanged` event. You should use NotificationBase's mechanism to set properties which will also raise the `PropertyChanged` event:

```
public class Custom_View_VM : NotificationBase
{
    private Brush color1;
    public Brush Color1 
    {
        get { return color1; }
        set { SetProperty(color1, value, () => color1 = value); }
    }
    // TODO: same here
    public Brush Color2 { get; set; }
    public void  ChangeColor{//change color1 or color2};
}
```

Also colors don't *usually* go into `ViewModels`. The `ViewModel` should have some business logic property that you can base the color of the `TextBox` from `XAML`, like `IsNameAvailable`.

Comment: thanks, but  get { return This.Color1; } throw a system.StackOverflowException :( i realy miss something><

Comment: Fixed my example, don't use `This` field from `NotificationBase`, it is too confusing. You can rename it to Model or something.

Comment: Thanks it work!
Now, I will follow you, and refactor my code :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the Property.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty Custom_Text_Field_Color_Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Custom_Text_Field_Color", typeof(Brush), 
        typeof(Class_Name), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        public Brush Custom_Text_Field_Color
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(Custom_Text_Field_Color_Property); }
            set { SetValue(Custom_Text_Field_Color_Property, value); }
        }
```

Use the Control Name (i.e., Class Name) for **`typeof(Class_Name)`**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already register my property in Custom_Text_Field code behind :)

Answer (score -1):

In you case class NotificationBase is a custom class, you can use is or not.

I only explain the MVVM design pattern in basically.
In ViewModel, it should be implement Interface INotifyPropertyChanged, and when set property, to trigger event PropertyChanged.

```
public sealed class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _productName;
    public string ProductName
    {
        get { return _productName; }
        set
        {
            _productName = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ProductName)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Under sample will demo this MVVM design pattern.
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-achieve-MVVM-design-2bb5a580